# Testing void strcpy(char *s, char *t) in K&R

Tags: c, strcpy

I'm testing the function void strcpy(char *s, char *t) I've just learned in K&R (page 106) but my codes (shown below) don't seem to work. Please help. Thanks a lot.

PS: I've changed the name of the function to strcpy1 to differentiate it from the built-in one in the standard library.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void strcpy1(char *s, char *t);

int main() {
char *m = "Love is beautiful";
char *n;
strcpy1(n, m);
printf("%s", n);
}

void strcpy1(char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s++ = *t++)
            ;
}
```

Comment: You did not allocate memory for `n`, try `char n[100];` or `char* n = malloc(100);`

Comment: Thanks, mnistic. I got it now. How can I vote up your answer? This is the first time I've asked a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @NienVan People aren't supposed to put answers in comments... welcome to StackOverflow :)  I have created an Answer that you can upvote and accept. Also, thanks for posting a clear question with a complete code example

Comment: it's also a super duplicate. so a comment + a duplicate closure is just as well.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Disagree with the duplicate ; there is no `scanf` in this question , it is hardly an "exact duplicate" although the answer is similar.

Comment: same root cause. A better duplicate can probably be found, but we're not creating 1 question by system call which is passed uninitialized pointers.

Comment: see? strcpy _and_ uninitialized pointer duplicate (linked to a canonical)

Comment: char *strcpy1(char *dest, const char *src); -learn proporly. function return the char * for possible use in the assingments or functions calls. src should be const. It is very important to learn how properly use **const**

Comment: Calling it `strcpy1` rather than `strcpy` (which is the name of a standard function) is a good start -- but all identifiers whose names start with `str` (or `mem`, or `wcs`) followed by a lowercase letter are reserved. `str_cpy()` is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You did not allocate memory for n, try `char n[100];` or `char* n = malloc(100);`.